# ANDROID ACCESS TOKEN ERROR - ErrorInsufficientPermissionsInAccessToken

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am getting the error below when attempting to validate a token on Postman. The access token is generated with my android app against a registered app on Azure. This has been working for more than a year and stopped a few days ago.

"error": {
"code": "ErrorInsufficientPermissionsInAccessToken",
"message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ProfileAccessDeniedException' was thrown.",
"innerError": {
"date": "",
"request-id": "",
"client-request-id": ""
}
}

Comment: Same problem here.  Was working OK until a few days ago.  The `scope` parameter that we are using is `openid email profile` and apparently Microsoft has changed/broken something.  Should we change the `scope` parameter value?

Comment: Something is indeed broken. I also only had the scope openid for at least 2 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `User.Read` to the `scope` parameter in the authentication redirection URL.

We had the same problem.  We were using `openid email profile` for the scope.  We have switched to `openid email profile User.Read` and now it works.

Reference:  [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I have added User.Read in my android application scope and it is still not working. Did you make any changes on the Azure application registration API permissions? In my case apart from the only minimal permission of openid I have had all along, I have had to add offline_access, User.Read.All and User.ReadWrite.All without success

Comment: The only change that we made to fix it was adding `User.Read` to the `scope` parameter in the redirection URL.

Comment: Hi, I have dropped all scopes I had previously listed in my android application and only retained User.Read and it is working. Not clear why openid is no longer being accepted but I will take this as a solution and adjust with it. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

**Tested in my environment working fine for me, using delegated permissions for the below API call as showing im image.**

[image]

**Permission which i have given to generate the token**

[image]

The same kind of problem has raised last year on [***Mircosoft Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/276867/problem-to-list-profilecardproperties.html) where multiple users were facing same kind of problem later it got fixed by micrsoft. would suggest you try to check if you are not missing any permissions that causing this error else you can directly raise the same question or follow up on same Mircosoft Q&A question.

Comment: RahulKumarShaw-MT, looks like you are testing with a user token with all possible scopes. I suggest you attempt with an access token with openid scope only and validate against https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ endpoint. Mine has been working for at least 2 years and only started failing a few days ago